# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Server Fault's [fifth moderator election](https://serverfault.com/election/5) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: EEAA] [image: HBruijn] [image: womble]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://serverfault.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://serverfault.com/election/5), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6219191036149760/0).

Comment: Congrats to all 3.  Here's to seeing Evan Carroll back around in 2016's election

Comment: Evan ... the [Screaming Lord Sutch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screaming_Lord_Sutch) of ServerFault, bless him.  Congrats to the new mods from me, too!

Comment: Congratulations! Try and stay around for a while now, so that we can skip next years election.

Comment: Congrat to the new moderator. Always cool to see good contributor to be named mod

Comment: Congrats to the new mods

Comment: It's probably time to remove the featured tag from this now.

Answer (score 15):

I think I speak for all my fellow fresh meat when I say: [bring it on](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhOrxkGlLDM).

Comment: Oh no, the end is nigh...